# Three numbers calculator

Tags: c++, calculator

**Edit**: I made a new calculator after taking your input [New Calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149577/three-function-calculator-2-0)

I made this three-function calculator. I have been learning C for a couple of months, and I learned C++ through the internet.
This is my first "real" program in C++, it started really messy but I did a lot of refining and debuging and deleting unnecessary code and this is the final result.
If you see any way to improve it or something I did wrong please tell me.

```
// Three numbers Calculator
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter action as # to exit program" << endl;
    cout << "Possible actions:+,-,*,/\n" << endl;
    while (1) //loop
    {
             long double num1, num2, num3, total;
         char action1, action2;
         cin >> num1 >> action1 >> num2 >> action2 >> num3;
         if (action1 == '/' && num2 == 0 || action2 == '/' && num3 == 0)
             cout << "You can't divide by zero" << endl;
         else if ((action2 == '*' || action2 == '/') && (action1 == '-' || action1 == '+'))  //action2 will be preformed before action1 (Order of operation)
         {
             switch (action2)  //I didn't include the options for '+' or '-' because the if statement requires action2 to be '*' or '/'.
             {
             case('/'):
                 total = num2 / num3;
                 break;
             case('*'):
                 total = num2*num3;
                 break;
             default:
                 cout << "Input not recognized";
                 break;
             }
             switch (action1)   //I didn't include the options for '*' or '/' because the if statement requires action1 to be '+' or '-'.
             {
             case('+'):
                 cout << num1 << "+" << num2 << action2 << num3 << "=" << total + num1;
                 break;
             case('-'):
                 cout << num1 << "-" << num2 << action2 << num3 << "=" << num1 - total;
                 break;
             default:
                 cout << "Input not recognized";
                 break;
             }
         }
         else //action1 will be performed before action2 (Order of operation)
         {
             switch (action1)
             {
             case('+'):
                 total = num1 + num2;
                 break;
             case('-'):
                 total = num1 - num2;
                 break;
             case('/'):
                 total = num1 / num2;
                 break;
             case('*'):
                 total = num1*num2;
                 break;
             case('#'):
                 system("PAUSE");
                 return 0;
                 break;
             default:
                 cout << "Input not recognized";
                 break;
             }
             switch (action2)
             {
             case('+'):
                 cout << num1 << action1 << num2 << "+" << num3 << "=" << total + num3;
                 break;
             case('-'):
                 cout << num1 << action1 << num2 << "-" << num3 << "=" << total - num3;
                 break;
             case('/'):
                  cout << num1 << action1 << num2 << "/" << num3 << "=" << total / num3;
                 break;      
             case('*'):
                 cout << num1 << action1 << num2 << "*" << num3 << "=" << total*num3;
                 break;
             case('#'):
                 system("PAUSE");
                 return 0;
                 break;
             default:
                 cout << "Input not recognized";
                 break;
             }
         }
         cout << "\n\n";
     }
}
```

---

### Update:

> Input: 7+8/2
>   Output: 7+8/2=11

Comment: Are you sure that `using namespace System;` is needed in your code. This is more like _C#_, please edit.

Comment: @Ziezi done, thank you. The compiler added it and I forgot to delete it

Comment: Prepare for answer recommending not to use `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Fix your formatting

The code as posted has inconsistent indenting which makes it hard to read.  Choose a particular style and apply it consistently to make your code easier to read.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Validate the input

The code does not seem to be able to handle negative numbers as in the expression:

```
-3+2
```

If it's not intended to handle negative numbers, it would be good to let the user know.  If it is, then there's a bug that should be fixed.

### Don't use `std::endl` if you don't really need it

The difference betweeen `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `'\n'` just emits a newline character, while `std::endl` actually flushes the stream.  This can be time-consuming in a program with a lot of I/O and is rarely actually needed.  It's best to *only* use `std::endl` when you have some good reason to flush the stream and it's not very often needed for simple programs such as this one.  Avoiding the habit of using `std::endl` when `'\n'` will do will pay dividends in the future as you write more complex programs with more I/O and where performance needs to be maximized.

### Don't use `system("PAUSE")`

There are two reasons not to use `system("cls")` or `system("PAUSE")`.  The first is that it is not portable to other operating systems which you may or may not care about now.  The second is that it's a security hole, which you absolutely **must** care about.  Specifically, if some program is defined and named `PAUSE` or `pause`, your program will execute that program instead of what you intend, and that other program could be anything.  First, isolate these into a seperate functions `pause()` and then modify your code to call those functions instead of `system`.  Then rewrite the contents of those functions to do what you want using C++.  For example:

```
void pause() {
    getchar();
}
```

### General portability

This code *could* be made portable if you omit the Windows-only include files `#include "stdafx.h"`.  If you must have `stdafx.h`, consider wrapping it so that the code is portable:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include "stdafx.h"
#endif
```

### Separate input, output and calculation

To the degree practical it's usually good practice to separate input, output and calculation for programs like this.  By putting them in separate functions, it isolates the particular I/O for your platform (which is likely to be unique to that platform or operating system) from the logic of the program (which does not depend on the underlying OS).  So for example, the `main` program might call a function to fetch and validate the input, a second function to actually perform the mathematical operations and then a third to emit the results.

### Omit spurious parentheses

The argument to a `case` statement or `return` statement does not need parentheses, so instead of this:

```
 case('#'):
```

One could write this:

```
 case '#':
```

### Consolidate strings

Right now, the string `"Input not recognized"` appears four times in the program.  I'd recommend creating a `const` variable instead and then using that instead of repeating the string.

Comment: could you explain the "fix your formating" part? Or give me examples. Also, what should I use insted of *system("PAUSE")*?

Comment: Most of the code is indented 4 spaces *except* for the `while` loop which is indented by only 1 space.  It would be nicer if the code were formatted more consistently.

Comment: Actually that was a mistake I made while inserting the code here. I didn't notice it

Comment: I do want the program to recognize negative numbers, any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving technicalities out, few general remarks regarding your code would be:

- Improve Style: try and add comments to your code to clarify its purpose and ease the readability. Ensure same code indentation.
- Increase modularity: try and separate the different phases/actions of your code in functions. For example: prompt message and input-reading, expression evaluation and result display. In this way it will be easier to spot a bug and correct it.

Few remarks on your question:

- Formulate clear question: for example, display an input-output example of your code and specify your areas of concern more specifically.

---

Now, about the calculator: a calculator does, roughly, the following things:

- reads input.
- parses input into tokens (operands and operations, functions, special characters); checks for expression validity.
- evaluates an expression: considering grammar, operation properties (precedence, arity, associativity).
- displays result.

The above could be used as guidelines to expand and further develop your calculator.

At this point, IMO, the best thing to do is to read some code (just research the subject and see what others have done), enrich your code-language vocabulary and use examples you find as benchmark / comparison.