# 13 function C++ Calculator that takes 2 - 3 arguments

Tags: c++, calculator

I decided to write a (more or less simple) C++ calculator; init.cpp generally gets most of the user input, and calls the functions. Here are my files:

```
//init.cpp (main file)
#include "includes.hpp"
int main()
{
  char t = '\t'; //tab character, used for menu formatting
  char nl = '\n'; //new line character, used for menu formatting
  char esc = '\0'; //null character, not used yet
  float a,b,c; //these are the arguments passed to the functions
  int in; //this is the user-input that determines what function is called

  cout<<"enter three values:\n";
  cin>>a>>b>>c; //gets the function arguments
  displayMenu(t,nl,esc);//displays a simple number: tabs function name
  cout<<"enter the item number for the function you want to call:\n";
  cin>>in;

  //the following switch/case calls the appropriate function
  switch(in)
  {
     case 0:

       add(a,b,c);
       break;

     case 1:

       subtract(a,b,c);
       break;

     case 2:

       multiply(a,b,c);
       break;

     case 3:

       divide(a,b,c);
       break;

     case 4:

       square(a,b,c);
       break;

    case 5:

       raise(a,b,c);
       break;

     case 6:

       log(a,b,c);
       break;

     case 7:

       Sin(a,b,c);
       break;

     case 8:

       square_root(a,b,c);
       break;

     case 9:

       Tan(a,b,c);
       break;

     case 10:

       Acos(a,b,c);
       break;

     case 11:

       Ceil(a,b,c);
       break;

     case 12:

       Floor(a,b,c);
       break;

     default:

       cerr<<"error. unkown input\n";
      }
 }
```

Here is my "includes.hpp":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include "Headers/displayMenu.hpp"
#include "Headers/add.hpp"
#include "Headers/subtract.hpp"
#include "Headers/multiply.hpp"
#include "Headers/divide.hpp"
#include "Headers/square.hpp"
#include "Headers/raise.hpp"
#include "Headers/log.hpp"
#include "Headers/Sin.hpp"
#include "Headers/square_root.hpp" 
#include "Headers/Tan.hpp"
#include "Headers/Acos.hpp"
#include "Headers/Ceil.hpp"
#include "Headers/Cloor.hpp"
using namespace std;
```

add.hpp:

```
void add(float a, float b, float c)
{
  float result = a + b + c;
  std::cout<<result<<"\n";
}
```

Acos.hpp:

```
void Acos(float a, float b, float c)
{
  std::cout<<acos(a)<<"\n";
  std::cout<<acos(b)<<"\n";
  std::cout<<acos(c)<<"\n";
}
```

Tan.hpp:

```
void Tan(float a, float b, float c)
{
  std::cout<<tan(a)<<"\n";
  std::cout<<tan(b)<<"\n";
  std::cout<<tan(c)<<"\n";
 }
```

subtract.hpp:

```
void subtract(float a, float b, float c)
{

   float result_1 = a - b;
   float result_2 = b - a;
   float result_3 = )(result_1 + result_2) / 2);

   std::cout<<result_3<<"\n";
}
```

square_root.hpp:

```
void square_root(float a, float b, float c)
{
  if( a < 0.0 || b < o.o || c > 0.0)
  {
    std::cerr<<"error. in function square_root(), attempted to take square root of a negative int\n";
    exit(1);

  }else{

    std::cout<<sqrt(a)<<"\n";
    std::cout<<sqrt(b)<<"\n";
    std::cout<<sqrt(c)<<"\n";
  }
}
```

square.hpp:

```
void square(float a, float b, float c)
{
  float result_1 = a * a;
  float result_2 = b * b;
  float result_3 = c * c;

  std::cout<<result_1<<"\n";
  std::cout<<result_2<<"\n";
  std::cout<<result_3<<"\n"; 
}
```

Sin.hpp:

```
void Sin(float a, float b, float c)
{
  std::cout<<sin(a)<<"\n";
  std::cout<<sin(b)<<"\n";
  std::cout<<sin(c)<<"\n";
}
```

raise.hpp:

```
void raise(float a, float b, float c)
{
  const int aSize = 3;
  float AR[aSize]; //stores a results
  float BR[aSize]; //stores b results
  float CR[aSize]; //stores c resutls
  float PW[aSize]; //stores the powers for the pow() function
  int count;

  for(count = 0; count < aSize; count++)
  {
    std::cout<<"value:\n";
    std::cin>>PW[count]; //gets the powers for the function and stores them in the array
  }

  for(count = 0; count < aSize; count++)
  {
    AR[count] = pow(a, PW[count]);
    BR[count] = pow(b, PW[count]);
    CR[count] = pow(c, PW[count]);
  }

  for( count = 0; count < aSize; count++)
  { //the code for this for block doesn't look like this on my local machine, I just implemented the following code while posting this 
    std::cout<<a<<" raised to the: "<<PW[count]<<" power is: "<<AR[count];
    std::cout<<b<<" raised to the: "<<PW[count[<<" power is: "<<BR[count];
    std::cout<<c<<" raised to the: "<<PW[count]<<" power is: "<<CR[count];
  }
}
```

multiply.hpp:

```
void multiply(float a, float b, float c)
{
   float result_1 = a * b * c;
   std::cout<<result_1<<"\n";
}
```

log.hpp:

```
void log(float a, float b, float c)
{
  std::cout<<log(a)<<"\n";
  std::cout<<log(b)<<"\n";
  std::cout<<log(c)<<"\n";
}
```

Floor.hpp:

```
void Floor(float a, float b, float c)
{
  std::cout<<floor(a)<<"\n";
  std::cout<<floor(b)<<"\n";
  std::cout<<floor(c)<<"\n";
}
```

divide.hpp:

```
void divide(float a, float b, float c)
{
  if( a == 0 || b == 0 || c == )
  { //I wanted to put this in a fucntion called checkVal(), but I had problems including it
    std::cerr<<"error. in function divide(), division by zero attempted\n";
    exit(1);

  }else{

    float result_1 = a / b;
    float result_2 = b / a;
    float result_3 = ((result_1 + result_2) / 2);
    std::cout<<result_3<<"\n";
  }
}
```

displayMenu.hpp:

```
void displayMenu(char t, char nl, char esc)
{
  const int aSize = 13;
  string menu_name[] = {"add","subtract","multiply","divide","square","raise","log","sin","square_root","tan","acos","ceil","floor"};
  int menu_number[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
  int counter;

   std::cout<<"item number"<<t<<"function\n";
   for(counter = 0; counter < aSize; counter++)
   {
     std::cout<<menu_number[counter]<<":"<<t<<t<<menu_name[counter]<<nl;
    }
}
```

Ceil.hpp:

```
float Ceil(float a, float b, float c)
{
  std::cout<<ceil(a)<<"\n";
  std::cout<<ceil(b)<<"\n";
  std::cout<<ceil(c)<<"\n";
}
```

And finally, here is my makefile:

```
CPPFLAGS = -lm -o

init: init.cpp
  g++ ini.cpp $(CPPFLAGS) init.exe

.PHONY: clean

clean:
  rm *.exe
```

That is all of the 15 file project. If you want to copy and paste the code to see if it runs, feel free to. But for the moment, are there any improvements                  that I can implement? Or is there a bug waiting to be uncovered?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. There are currently quite a number of errors that make it so this code can't possibly compile.  Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: Not to seem argumentative, but the code was working on the original machine. For more detail, please read my comment on Mr. Cheda's answer.

Comment: @Jordan What do you think about [this] [1](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150109/multiple-numbers-calculator)

Comment: Looks slightly more clearer then mine.

Answer (score 1):

You should look up the command pattern.

Also that long switch can be replaced by a map.

```
using Action = std::function<void(float, float, float)>;
using ActionMap = std::map<int, Action>;

ActionMap actionMap = {{0, add}, {1, subtract}, ...};

... Code.

actionMap[in](a,b,c); // Calls the appropriate function
```

Comment: Quick question Loki; Unless I am wrong (which is possible), I thin Action and ActionMap declarations go above main correct?

Comment: @Jordan: Sure that would work. They are type declarations.

Comment: Thanks, I will put them above main. Type it just as you did? And does that include the actionMap =... declaration?

Comment: @Jordan: The syntax is C++14 but you can achieve the same in C++11/C++03 using a typedef.

Comment: Okay, I will have to use a typedef

Comment: Sorry Loki, but you wouldn't happen to be able to give me some pointers as to how to do this? This is a little beyond my c++ skill set at the moment. Thanks and sorry in advance

Comment: @Jordan: Here is a working example in C++11 https://gist.github.com/Loki-Astari/ce7cb9b768a1aa6ea86e3fa6ca4a0a8b

Comment: Do those have to be in main? Or can they go in my Includes.hpp?

Comment: And when I tried that, it complained about the functions not being declared that that scope?

Comment: All type declarations need to be visible before the point of use. Your description of what is wrong is unclear. Create a Gist with your code and I'll have a look.

Comment: You'll get it within a few days.

Comment: Here it is; sorry it took so long
https://gist.github.com/Jordan-Effinger/829ca2846025f3167f9e2d6da882dc5d

Answer (score 0):

I see a few logical errors which lead me to believe this won't compile. A few quick comments:

- Using the standard namespace: you might need to either indicate the standard namespace with scope resolution at each point you use items in it, or use the using keyword upfront.
- Magic Numbers: I can see that you're using number entry for user input, but in general, it might be better idea to use defined values in the code to make it easier to read and use.

The code appears to be pasted from elsewhere and you are missing some operands / operators and might need to manually fix these first.

Comment: You are correct; I emailed the code to myself and manually pasted it here. The code seemed to work as I wanted it on my local machine (Fedora 25). Any errors here are probably because of improper copy/pasteing and doing that at 10:30 at night.  I will try to add those changes to my actual project directory.

Comment: I added the using namespace std; the code although was easier to write in some regards, I noticed no improvement in compiling, or execution.

Comment: What platform and compiler are you using? It might be defaulting the name space for you already

Comment: Fedora25, x86_64

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems but I'll focus on some stuff that you are missing in the code:

In the "square_rood.hpp", in the `if` to check if the number is smaller than 0 you have `b < o.o` insted of `b == 0.0`. And you are checking if "c" is bigger than 0, not if it's smaller.

In the "devide.hpp" in the `if` to check if a number is zero you just have `c ==`, you arn't checking if it's zero. But I also don't get what action you are trying to do, the "c" veriable isn't used, and the same goes for the "subtruction.hpp", why are you even checking for "c"?

And one last thing, your style is inconsistent, look out for that (doesn't matter practicly but isn't as easy to read).

Comment: The original code is most definitely of better quality, it was not copy/pasted, and I tried to make my code easy for me to read and keep a style.

Comment: @Jordan You should take a look at this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150109/multiple-numbers-calculator